# How to set a specific default html/php document a directory

Tags: html, file, directory, default

I have a directory on my webspace ("test"), in which the file abc.php is placed. When I enter the following URL in the browser the document should be loaded:
mywebspace.com/test/

I dont want to name it index.php and in the adressbar should stand "mywebspace.com/test/" and not(!) "mywebspace.com/test/abc.php".

Is this possible? And how?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a directory named **test** you can write this `.htaccess` file: `DirectoryIndex test/`

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
DirectoryIndex test/       
order deny,allow
```